# How to convert dates in R from multiple formats at once?

Tags: r, string, date

I have a source column in a dataframe, where dates may be either in "dd.mm.yyyy" format or in Excel format of 5-digit number. Hence, I would like to check with `ifelse`, how the element looks like with `str_detect` and then use appropriate conversion for each.

```
df$date <- ifelse(str_detect(df$date, "[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}") == TRUE, 
                      as.Date(df$date, format = "%d.%m.%Y"),
                      as.Date(as.numeric(df$date), origin = "1899-12-30"))
```

While both conversion functions work as intended on their own, when I put them into `ifelse` statement, I got weird results - basically 1st Jan 2019 becomes "17897". Can somebody explain why is that happening and how I can make it work? Thanks

Edit: code snippet

```
  df <- c("01.01.2019", "43867")
  df <- ifelse(str_detect(df, "[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}") == TRUE,
                      as.Date(df, format = "%d.%m.%Y"),
                      as.Date(as.numeric(df), origin = "1899-12-30"))
```

Desired output: `"2019-01-01" "2020-02-06"`
Resulted output  `17897 18298`
Where if I apply first (yes) function without `ifelse`, I will get `"2019-01-01" NA`, and no function results in `NA "2020-02-06"`

Comment: Interesting problem, it'd be good to have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with a snippet of the data to test solutions against.

Comment: could you give examples and expected output

Comment: Read the help page of `ifelse`, particularly the Warning.

Comment: we need an example, however if the variables as stored as date objects I do not understand why you cant coerce them to numerics and then you can play with timestamps. if you use dput() you can show us more precisely what the problem is

Comment: added code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the data to numeric, dates which are not numbers would be changed to `NA` (with a warning which is safe to ignore), we can then use `if_else` to change them to Date based on it.

```
df <- c("01.01.2019", "43867")
df1 <- as.numeric(df)
dplyr::if_else(is.na(df1), as.Date(df, format = "%d.%m.%Y"),
                as.Date(df1, origin = "1899-12-30"))
#[1] "2019-01-01" "2020-02-06"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the class, as stated in the help page of ifelse. No need to load other packages.

```
> class(df) <- "Date"
> df
[1] "2019-01-01" "2020-02-06"
```